# Correct way to free memory for a structure that contains allocated memory referenced by pointers

Tags: c, free

I have the following function:

```
/* undef: from s from hashtab */
void undef(char *s) {
    struct nlist *currentPtr, *previousPtr;

    for (previousPtr = NULL, currentPtr = hashtab[hash(s)];
            currentPtr != NULL;
            previousPtr = currentPtr, currentPtr = currentPtr->next) {

        if (strcmp(currentPtr->name, s) == 0) {
            if (previousPtr == NULL) /* first element */
                hashtab[hash(s)] = currentPtr->next;
            else /* element in the middle or at the end */
                previousPtr->next = currentPtr->next;
            /* free memory */
            free(currentPtr->name);
            free(currentPtr->defn);
            //free(currentPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

`currentPtr` points to a memory allocated by `malloc`.

`currentPtr->name` and `currentPtr->defn` point to character arrays copied via `strdup`.

I am not sure what is the correct way to free the memory of a list item.

If I use

```
free(currentPtr->name);
free(currentPtr->defn);
```

then I get no segmentation fault, but I believe the character array memory is freed, but the list structure element itself is not.

If I use

```
free(currentPtr);
```

then I also get no segmentation fault, but I believe I freed the list structure element itself, but not the character array memory.

Using

```
free(currentPtr->name);
free(currentPtr->defn);
free(currentPtr);
```

gives me segmentation fault. But I thought that would be the correct way of doing it.

So which is correct? Why does it fail?

Comment: FWIW, `strdup` is just `malloc` under the hood. So you don't treat the return value from `strdup` any differently than you would that of `malloc`.

Comment: Freeing the memory to which `currentPtr` points makes `currentPtr`'s value invalid.  If you then dereference it before assigning it a new, valid value then the behavior is undefined.  Even if it seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change your strategy a little bit since `currentPtr` is a dangling pointer after the call to

```
free(currentPtr);
```

Here's my suggestion:

```
for (previousPtr = NULL, currentPtr = hashtab[hash(s)];
        currentPtr != NULL;
        previousPtr = currentPtr) {

    if (strcmp(currentPtr->name, s) == 0)
    {
        if (previousPtr == NULL) /* first element */
            hashtab[hash(s)] = currentPtr->next;
        else /* element in the middle or at the end */
            previousPtr->next = currentPtr->next;

        /* free memory */
        free(currentPtr->name);
        free(currentPtr->defn);

        // Get hold of the next pointer before free'ing currentPtr
        struct nlist *tempPtr = currentPtr->next;
        free(currentPtr);
        currentPtr = tempPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }
}
```

**Update, a more streamlined version**

Since you are using `currentPtr->next` in four places, you can streamline the loop by using:

```
struct nlist *nextPtr = NULL;
for (previousPtr = NULL, currentPtr = hashtab[hash(s)];
        currentPtr != NULL;
        previousPtr = currentPtr, currentPtr = nextPtr) {

    nextPtr = currentPtr->next;
    if (strcmp(currentPtr->name, s) == 0)
    {
        if (previousPtr == NULL) /* first element */
            hashtab[hash(s)] = nextPtr;
        else /* element in the middle or at the end */
            previousPtr->next = nextPtr;

        /* free memory */
        free(currentPtr->name);
        free(currentPtr->defn);
        free(currentPtr);
    }
}
```